# Remove UTC from Datepicker when editing entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the UTC from `worked_at` for the date picker that I currently have when I have a `check_in` that is being edited.

here's the code for the `date_picker`

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

Choosing the time looks like this:

[image: Choosing time]

Editing a check in like this:

[image: Editing a check in]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I just need to change the format for the `edit` not the `new`.

Comment: You should post your datepicker initialization code and how you have used it in your template.

Comment: `$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});`

This is what we have for the date picker right now, it doesn't seem to do anything if I change it.

Comment: `worked_at` is a `DATE` field or `DATETIME` field ?   If you have it as a `DATETIME` field type then Rails saves a date & time(UTC) in the db. So when you edit the same attribute in your form, you get the additional `TIME (in UTC)` info as well. So convert `DATETIME` field type to `DATE` field.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: glad it worked for you! I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worked_at` is a `datetime` field type. For a `datetime` field, Rails saves date along with time(in UTC) in the db.

When you edit the same attribute in your form, you get the additional **TIME (in UTC)** info as well.

So, convert `DATETIME` field type to `DATE` field.